# Create an inline form with input-groups bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a simple inline form using input groups to display icons before the inputs. As far as I'm aware of I'm following the documentation but the form doesn't display as expected. [See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9cp8/1/), it demonstrates the problem. I assumed [it should be displayed like this](http://jsfiddle.net/24y3L/) (only with the icons prepended of course). How can this be solved?

My code:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">    
        <div class="input-group">                       
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose password"/>
        </div>
    </div>                          

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create account</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i've made it work like this:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>

            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>

            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose password" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create account</button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5qmc/

Comment: This doesn't work, while the form is rendered it is not displayed inline; which is the goal.

Comment: It depends on screen resolution, you could change col size to sm?

Comment: I see what you're doing, you're placing the inputs in seperate columns. Not really my desired solution, but I'll work with this. Thanks :) +1A

Comment: After 1h battling with this issue I ended up taking this. thks

Comment: Two reasons nobody should use this:

First: you should never mix `form-group` with `col-*` -- in fact you shouldn't mix _anything_ with `col-*` classes.

Second: Only `col-*` classes can be direct descendants of `row`s. The final `button` should also be wrapped in a `col-*`.

Answer (score 33):

This is known issue and will be fixed in Bootstrap v.3.2.0 according to [this ship list](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12736).

Before that you can fix it your self like this:

```
.input-group {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;

    .input-group-addon,
    .input-group-btn,
    .form-control {
        width: auto !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm both statements above to be correct :)

Comment: Thank you. I was getting quite frustrated with myself thinking I had done everything according to the documentation.  I just needed an upgrade.

Comment: it wasn't fixed in 3.3.6

Comment: This works, but what's up with the brackets? My validator claims those nested brackets are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

### Taken from Bootstrap Docs

Use Bootstrap's predefined grid classes to align labels and groups of form controls in a horizontal layout by adding `.form-horizontal` to the form. Doing so changes `.form-group`s to behave as grid rows, so no need for `.row`. 
I also added in semantic attributes for the labels you should always be using on every input (use `.sr-only` to hide the labels if necessary).  This makes the form not *inline* but *horizontal*.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
          <div class="input-group col-sm-3"> 
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>
              </span>                            
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <div class="input-group col-sm-3"> 
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose password" />
            </div>  
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create account</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, but I thought I would post as I haven't seen this elsewhere. I was trying to get an inline form with inline labels and an add-on using Bootstrap v3. Here is the code that worked for me. I used the grid system in divs to position the label and input group and the add-on within a grid item.

```
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <label class="control-label" for="input_one">Label Text</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Placeholder Text" type="text" name="input_one" id="input_one">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Add on text</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```